# Check nested component loaded

Tags: angular

I would like to perform a function after the component and its nested component is loaded completly in the DOM.

I already tried the life cicle hooks of angular and the javascript DomContentLoaded function. But nothing of them are working of the nested component.

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-my',
    templateUrl: `
<div>
    <app-nested-component></app-nested-component>
</div>`,
    styleUrls: ['./my.component.css']
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {

        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
            // not working
        });

    }

}
```

So, my goal was if all components are completly loaded perform a function.

I use route with a fragment and want to scroll to a anchor. But scrolling to the anchor will be before the nested components completly rendered.

Comment: ngOnInit should work, what's problem in that?

Comment: That's not working. I use route with a fragment and want to scroll to a anchor. But scrolling to the anchor will be before the nested components completly rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Just call you function in `ngAfterViewChecked` life cycle hook of component in angular.

> ngAfterViewChecked() -
>   Respond after Angular checks the component's views and child views / the view that a directive is in.
>
> Called after the ngAfterViewInit and every subsequent ngAfterContentChecked().

- https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Comment: i updated my question because i want to use a route with a fragment and want to scroll to a anchor. But scrolling to the anchor will be before the nested components completly rendered.

Comment: Yes, so have you tried calling your function in ngAfterViewChecked hook?